# Build a cluster consists of 3 linux machines using JGroups

Tags: java, network-programming, jgroups

I would build a cluster consist of three Lunix machines by using the JGroups. The code is running fine, but each machine works independently and apparently there is no clustering.

However, when I run the code in single machine as standalone and I create 3 instances, it works  fine and forms a cluster. So I believe the problem is not the code.

The following is the java code and `UDP.XML` file.

```
package com.github.dustinbarnes;

import org.jgroups.JChannel;
import org.jgroups.ReceiverAdapter;
import org.jgroups.View;
import org.jgroups.blocks.locking.LockService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

@SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
public class Node extends ReceiverAdapter
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Node.class);

    private AtomicBoolean isMaster = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private Thread statusPrinter;
    private Thread acquiringThread;
    private LockService lockService;
    private JChannel channel;
    private Lock masterLock;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.start();
    }

    public Node() throws Exception
    {
        this.channel = new JChannel(Node.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("udp.xml"));
        this.channel.setReceiver(this);
        this.channel.connect("master-cluster");
        this.lockService = new LockService(this.channel);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        this.startAcquiringThread();
        this.startStatusPrintingThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void viewAccepted(View view)
    {
        LOG.info("Cluster event has happened!");
    }

    private void startAcquiringThread()
    {
        acquiringThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Thread.currentThread().setName("acquire-lock");
                getLock();
            }
        };

        acquiringThread.setDaemon(true);
        acquiringThread.start();
    }

    private void getLock()
    {
        masterLock = lockService.getLock("master");
        masterLock.lock();

        isMaster.set(true);
        LOG.info("I have become the master!");
    }

    private void startStatusPrintingThread()
    {
        statusPrinter = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Thread.currentThread().setName("status-printer");

                //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
                while ( true ) {
                    try
                    {
                        LOG.info("is master [" + isMaster + "]");
                        LOG.info("cluster view [" + channel.getViewAsString() + "]");
                        sleep(2000L);
                    }
                    catch ( InterruptedException e )
                    {
                        // If the sleep gets interrupted, that's fine.
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        statusPrinter.setDaemon(true);
        statusPrinter.start();
    }
}
```

This is UDP file:-

```
<!--
  Default stack using IP multicasting. It is similar to the "udp"
  stack in stacks.xml, but doesn't use streaming state transfer and flushing
  author: Bela Ban
-->

<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/JGroups-3.1.xsd">
<UDP mcast_port="${jgroups.udp.mcast_port:45588}" tos="8" ucast_recv_buf_size="20M" ucast_send_buf_size="640K" mcast_recv_buf_size="25M" mcast_send_buf_size="640K" loopback="true" max_bundle_size="64K" max_bundle_timeout="30" ip_ttl="${jgroups.udp.ip_ttl:8}" enable_bundling="true" enable_diagnostics="true" thread_naming_pattern="cl"

    timer_type="old" timer.min_threads="4" timer.max_threads="10" timer.keep_alive_time="3000" timer.queue_max_size="500"

    thread_pool.enabled="true" thread_pool.min_threads="2" thread_pool.max_threads="8" thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000" thread_pool.queue_enabled="true" thread_pool.queue_max_size="10000" thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"

    oob_thread_pool.enabled="true" oob_thread_pool.min_threads="1" oob_thread_pool.max_threads="8" oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000" oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false" oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100" oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard" />

<PING timeout="2000" num_initial_members="20" />
<MERGE2 max_interval="30000" min_interval="10000" />
<FD_SOCK />
<FD_ALL />
<VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500" />
<BARRIER />
<pbcast.NAKACK2 xmit_interval="1000" xmit_table_num_rows="100" xmit_table_msgs_per_row="2000" xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000" max_msg_batch_size="500" use_mcast_xmit="false" discard_delivered_msgs="true" />
<UNICAST xmit_interval="2000" xmit_table_num_rows="100" xmit_table_msgs_per_row="2000" xmit_table_max_compaction_time="60000" conn_expiry_timeout="60000" max_msg_batch_size="500" />
<pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="4M" />
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="3000" view_bundling="true" />
<UFC max_credits="2M" min_threshold="0.4" />
<MFC max_credits="2M" min_threshold="0.4" />
<FRAG2 frag_size="60K" />
<RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000" />
<pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER />
<CENTRAL_LOCK/>
<!-- pbcast.FLUSH  /-->
```

Comment: +1 for a well formed question. Can you explain how you know that there is no clustering when deployed to three machines, and how you know that there is clustering on a single node?

Comment: Yes, the code that I am running is dead-simple leader election mechanism through shared locks. When I run it in standalone creating 2 instancea, it shows me in one machine console "is a master [true]". In the onther machine console "is a master [false]" meaning that only one member can be a leader in cluster. However, if I run in mult machines all machines print "is a master [true]" meaning the member does interact with other. Also I use SimpleChat application, i am able to send and receive a message to all member in standalone, whereas in multi machines the member can only send to himself.

Comment: Check that multicast is enabled on your network interface

Comment: Yes, it is enable. sh-4.2$ netstat -g
IPv6/IPv4 Group Memberships
Interface       RefCnt Group
--------------- ------ ---------------------
lo              1      224.0.75.75
lo              1      all-systems.mcast.net
em1             1      224.0.75.75
em1             1      228.8.8.8
em1             1      all-systems.mcast.net
lo              2      ff0e::75:75
lo              1      ff02::1
lo              1      ff01::1
em1             2      ff0e::75:75
em1             2      ff0e::8:8:8
em1             1      ff02::1:ff1f:3c6d

Comment: ip maddr show
1: lo
 inet  224.0.75.75
 inet  224.0.0.1
 inet6 ff0e::75:75 users 2
 inet6 ff02::1
 inet6 ff01::1
2: em1
 link  33:33:00:00:00:01
 link  01:00:5e:00:00:01
 link  33:33:ff:1f:3c:6d
 link  01:00:5e:08:08:08
 link  01:00:5e:00:4b:4b
 link  33:33:00:08:00:08
 link  33:33:00:75:00:75
 inet  224.0.75.75
 inet  228.8.8.8
 inet  224.0.0.1
 inet6 ff0e::75:75 users 2
 inet6 ff0e::8:8:8 users 2
 inet6 ff02::1:ff1f:3c6d
 inet6 ff02::1
 inet6 ff01::1

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you bind to a routable IP address: 127.0.0.1 will *not* work
- Make sure the firewall has holes for the ports required: you can test this by turning the firewall off via iptables -F
- Use McastSenderTest/McastReceiverTest to see if multicasts are received between the hosts

Comment: How to bind to a routable IP addres using JGroups.

Comment: I have found that there is firewall runing on the network that I am using. So I think the firewall block the IP Mulicast protocol. So, there is FILE PING protocl that seem to me suitable. but I do not to configure it? any help?